# Web Garden properties on IIS 6.0 running several ASP.NET web sites

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Is there any logic in setting the number of maximum number of worker processes to more than 1, in a setup where there is few ASP.NET websites hosted on one server, and a call to one website issues a call to another server (outside the farm) which in turn calls another web-site on the server (and once a result is return from the 2nd site to the external server , the last returns the 1st server call and everyone is happy...)

it usually works well (with 1 set at web-garden), but sometimes, the outside server gets a 503 error from the 2nd site (Service unavailable) which I don't know where to tie it....

will it do any good ?

(this is semi server-fault question , but I'm looking from the development perspective).

I saw the warning [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290955/asp-net-increase-maxprocesses-web-garden-using-state-server-and-caching) So I need to understand how this setting might effect the sites I run on this server.

I've checked http.sys error log and found nothing.

Comment: Are you expecting us to make the assumption that the ASP.NET web sites all run in the same Application pool?

Comment: They are, sorry for not stating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a "development" point of view I'd put that "2nd site" (the one returning 503) in its own application pool. If that is already the case then mucking about with Web Gardens might fix it, might cause other problems, doesn't tell you why you were getting 503's in the first place.

Comment: Everything goes to the same default app pool.
Does each app pool has it's own process ? would it be enough ?
Server has 1 CPU (probably more, but that is what allocated to this instance)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about the maximum number of worker process, is very dependent on your processor architecture you have on the machine.  If you have multiple processors, you could increase this, and as far as I know the "formula" for this is the amount of processors you have.  So if you have a quad processor machine increasing the number of worker processes to 4 could result in better performance.  I would keep a eye on performance monitor to make sure that the the reduce overhead has not started increasing resource locking.

Best Regards 
Rihan